# List of dictionary to an expression

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

Python v3.4.3

Given list of dictionaries:

```
dlist = [{'Bilbo':'Ian','Frodo':'Elijah'},{'Bilbo':'Martin','Thorin':'Richard'}]
```

and a variable k

```
k = 'Frodo'
```

Task is to write an expresion to asign list  from dictionary, where key doesn't exist must be shown 'not present', all problem must be solved in 1 line.

I have written line that gives desirable output :

```
for kk in dlist : kk[k] if k in kk else 'NOT PRESENT'
```

the output:

```
'Elijah'
'NOT PRESENT'
```

but the problem is that I can't assign this output to variable

```
res = list(for kk in dlist : kk[k] if k in kk else 'NOT PRESENT')
```

or

```
res = [for kk in dlist : kk[k] if k in kk else 'NOT PRESENT']
```

EDIT: 
In addition this gives correct assignment if all dictionaries have desired key

```
res = [x[k] for x in dlist]
```

but I cant combine 
dictionary[key] if 'key' in dictionary

with for kk in dictionarylist

After abhinsit answered this question and gave me some insights: I've solved it without .get

```
output = [item[k] if k in item else 'NOT PRESENT' for item in dlist]
```

The main problem for me was the correct position of else statement.

Comment: Briefly: that is not the proper syntax for a comprehension, which is what you're looking for. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you provided the expected result (not the output when printing). Also, remove the "Python343" from the title, that's what the separate tags are for.

Comment: Also, check out `kk.get(k, 'NOT PRESENT')`.

Comment: Removed Python343 from title and gave expected result without condition(if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dlist = [{'Bilbo':'Ian','Frodo':'Elijah'},{'Bilbo':'Martin','Thorin':'Richard'}]
>>> required_key = 'Frodo'
>>> output = [item.get(required_key,'NOT PRESENT')for item in dlist]
>>> output
['Elijah', 'NOT PRESENT']
>>>
```

Comment: Ty for your answer it gives desirable result, but the same task is doable without using item.get.

Comment: yes there are different ways to get / check value in a dictionary, it all depends how you want to implement it. You may have written a if instead of get

Comment: Yes the problem for me was that else is mandatory, and else position must be not at the very end, with your advise I get desirable output with if
[item[k] if k in item else 'NOT PRESENT' for item in dlist]